# Validate that I received info from raw_input function

Tags: python

I have this raw input function

```
player = raw_input("Please enter your name")
```

at very beginning of my code. I don't know how to ensure that the user typed something. When I just press enter without typing anything, the script just continues. The script should continue only if I have the name. Please can someone help me here?

Comment: I need continually to ask the user to type name until he did it

Answer (score 1):

You can just check it as follows:

```
player = ""

while len(player) < 2:     #assuming name is at least 2 characters long
    player = raw_input("Please enter your name: ")
```

Comment: @user3437668, No problem. Glad I could be of help.

Answer (score 1):

The way I generally approach this kind of input is:

```
while True:
    player = raw_input(...)
    if player: # will reject an empty string
        break
    print("Not a valid name.")
```

This makes it very easy to add extra checking and puts the `raw_input` in only one place, without having to define a "null value" beforehand.

Comment: Thanks! I have a question why if player rejects an empty string??

Comment: Because `bool("") == False`; Python evaluates empty sequences as `False`, see http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations

Answer (score 0):

Just pressing enter in raw_input() without typing anything else will return a empty string with length 0.

```
>>> len(raw_input())
something
9
>>> len(raw_input())

0
>>>
```

So you can just check the length of the return string to ensure if the user has typed anything as sshashank124 has suggested.

```
player = ""
while len(player) < 1:
    player = raw_input("Please enter your name")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
player = "" # typing 'not player' into the console will return True for an empty string

while not player:
    player = raw_input("Please enter your name: ")
```

This will loop until such time as typing `not player` would return `False` because the string is no longer empty